# Do the cyclic or Hochschild homologies satisfy the addition axiom of Eilenberg Steenrod?

Tags: homological-algebra, schemes, homology-cohomology, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

Do the cyclic or Hochschild homologies satisfy the addition axiom of ES?
If so please provide a reference or proof (reference is preferable).

Comment: It might help if you stated the axiom in its precise form in the setting your interested in.